# Convert varchar special characters to nvarchar with trigger

Tags: sql-server, casting, sql-server-2012, varchar, nvarchar

I need to create a trigger to insert on another table whenever a data is inserted.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [site].trg_registered
ON  [site].[customer] 
AFTER INSERT,UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE 
@customerid int,
@name nvarchar
@expire date

SELECT @customerid = customerid, @expire = expire, @name = name
FROM INSERTED


UPDATE [dbo].[customers]
SET [expiredate] = @expire, [name] = @name
WHERE [Id] = @customerid

END
GO
```

But, the column [name] on [site].[customer] is varchar, and the column [name] on [dbo].[customers] is nvarchar.
And I have data like "NÃ£o ArÃ§a" on the varchar column, and I need to convert to the real representation of nvarchar, which is "Não Arça"

I already tried `cast([name] as nvarchar)` and `convert(nvarchar,[name])` but it gives me the unicode for every single "ugly" character

I have no more ideas, is this possible??

Thanks

Comment: Can you change the datatype of [name] on [site].[customer]?   I'm afraid after the data was implicitly converted to varchar you can't convert it back to nvarchar and get the expected results.

Comment: Unfortunatly no, I am using db-library on my site, which doesnt support unicode

Comment: Maybe you can use the CHAR() function to create a UDF that maps the varchar characters to the nvarchar characters you want to replace them with.   Maybe.

Comment: I had this idea too, but was thinking of a easier way, well, I will do this and post a function to replace or whatever... Thanks :)